# Object reference not set to an instance of an object (timer array)

Tags: c#, timer, object-reference

I am using the following code but getting error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on line 2.

```
System.Timers.Timer[] timer = new System.Timers.Timer[10];
timer[0].Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DoJob);
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you forget to initialize array's item

```
System.Timers.Timer[] timer = new System.Timers.Timer[10];
timer[0] = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer[0].Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DoJob);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first line creates an array. An array of Timer references. An array of Timer references that *all have a value of null*.